# Xcode JIT compiler ignores some preprocessor macros

Tags: objective-c

This problem is driving me mad and it almost certainly relates to some bug in Xcode, but maybe there's some workaround that I'm not familiar with or something I might have overlooked. Here it goes:

We have several build targets for different sub-projects that generate separate executables with partially overlapping code. To exclude certain bits of the code that should not go in one or the other app, we define a number of `#define` macros in the respective .pch files for each sub-project, e.g. in *main-app.pch*

```
#ifndef MY_APP
    #define MY_APP 1
#endif
```

and in *sub-app.pch*

```
#ifndef SUB_APP
    #define SUB_APP 1
#endif
```

Then, in some code, you'd see

```
- (void)doSomething
{
#ifdef MY_APP
    NSLog(@"This is just an example");
#endif
}
```

Now, the problem is that Xcode sometimes, ie only on *some* machines, doesn't do syntax highlighting or code completion of the conditionally compiled code. That is, for my colleague it works perfectly fine, whereas I never see syntax highlighting no matter what I do. For the record, we're all on Xcode 4.5.2. I tried removing derived data and re-indexing, shuffling the order of the targets/schemas and also to put the preprocessor macros in the Project and in the Target settings instead of the .pch file, but nothing seems to help. Any idea anyone what's going on here?

Comment: Additional information: the problem seems to be that Xcode gets confused about which target a file belongs to, if that file is part of multiple sub-projects. Even though I have X set as the current build target, the jit compiler compiles it as if I had project B with target Y set.

Comment: In fact, it seems that the problem is that there is a build dependency between project A and B, so B gets compiled before A and so files that occur in both projects are compiled as B first, and then never touched again.

Answer (score 0):

After spending most of the day on this annoying problem, I have found a "solution" of sorts: use Xcode workspaces instead of sub-projects for independent executables that all belong to the same app bundle. Instead of creating build dependencies, I now add the additional targets in the "Build" part of the current scheme (**Product**->**Edit scheme...**).